# I have multiple files of `.zcompdump` , why do I have multiple files of these?

Tags: zsh

I have multiple files of `.zcompdump*`.

```
.rw-r--r--   47k myuser 13 Jul 10:02  .zcompdump
.rw-r--r--   47k myuser 14 Jul 16:52  .zcompdump-MacBook Pro (2)-5.7.1
.rw-r--r--   47k myuser  4 Jun  9:32  .zcompdump-MacBook Pro-5.7.1
.rw-r--r--   36k myuser  3 Jul 11:07  .zcompdump.macbook-pro-2.lan.54221
```

Which one of them do `zsh` actually use? Can i clear out some of them or?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Because the `compinit` mechanism of zsh creates the filename depending on some environment variable, here $HOST.

> It's safe to delete them, but they will be recreated unless you add -D to compinit line in your zsh config

https://github.com/wurmlab/oswitch/issues/41

They are used to speed up the completion mechanism.
You can delete them and let it recreate the one you need.

Answer (score 61):

I added this line to the `~/.zshrc` above the `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` line:

```
export ZSH_COMPDUMP=$ZSH/cache/.zcompdump-$HOST
```

Then, when we `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`, the `compinit` command dumps to that new location.

Here's where [`compinit` is](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/oh-my-zsh.sh#L126-L129) in oh-my-zsh.sh.

Comment: Bless you. So sick of programs dumping caches, histories etc. to $HOME - it's not acceptable behaviour for any program

Comment: There is an old PR to do something similar [here](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/pull/9090). Hopefully it will get approved and merged.

Answer (score 4):

I figured someone would need this, based on "***the Tin Man***" answer:

```bash
sed -i -e "/source \$ZSH\/oh-my-zsh.sh/i export ZSH_COMPDUMP=\$ZSH\/cache\/.zcompdump-\$HOST" ~/.zshrc
```

It saves you the time of opening a file to find a specific line.